# mod_rewrite - error with 2 variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

just a quick one, I'm using this rule and it works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /profile.php?id=$1
```

so whatever come to mysite.com/anything will be read as mysite.com/profile.php?id=anything
That's all good.

Then I need to add another variable so I used:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ /profile.php?id=$1&vid=$2
```

Which kind of works but it doesn't load any css, js, external php...
I guess that's why it's looking in a different folder, I don't know how to tell it get those other files from the root folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: What base did you set in your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are creating **virutal folders** using the htaccess. If you want to load your CSS and JS properly, either use **absolute paths** or add **../** before your relative path (which means "one folder up").

Another possibility is to add `<base href="www.example.com">`. Which will cause all new requests (for images, external files, etc) to be relative to that path, and not the current address.

Comment: yeah, I've just added ../ to all my css and js files and it's working nicely..
just wondering now, when I added ../ to php includes: include("../scripts/xx.php")

it didn't like it but works without the ../

Comment: That's because PHP does not request the file through the apache webserver, it just accesses the files themselves. Also @matt if you find my answer good, please consider upvoting it and accepting it. It will help me and any future developer searching for the same problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```

to do not rewrite URL if there are files with this URL

Comment: It's not the regular expressions matching js or css files - anything with a period in it (including `css/style.css`) will not be matched.

Comment: @Daan Wilmer: seems that we understand the question differently

Answer (score 1):

Add next 2 lines befor RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
```